# trying to compare multiple lines in a text file and print by joining them

Tags: python

How to compare multiple lines and join the lines based on the first word if they are same using python
I am a beginner to python and trying to compare multiple lines in a text file and print by joining them.

Text file

```
Rolt12 is a musician
Rolt1 is dancer
Rolt1 is an actor
Rolt14 is a singer
```

I am trying to print

```
Rolt12 is a musician
Rolt1 is a dancer; is an actor
Rolt14 is a singer
```

So far I know the opening and writing into the file

```
with open ('input.txt','r') as ifh, with open ('out.txt', 'w') as ofh:
    ifh.readlines()
```

After this, I think I should compare the lines in a text file and check whether the first is same or no. Later, join them if the first word is the same. But I am not sure how to compare and join them. Any help would be appreciated....Thank you

Comment: please format your code as such

Comment: do you want to use an output file or do you want to print it in the console

Comment: i want to use the output file

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using the dictionary split each line into two parts one with 'name' and other part(rest of the line without name). Use name as key in the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for line in fp:
        x = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        d[x[0]].append(x[1])

#writing output to new file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for k, v in d.items():
        fw.write( k + ' ' + '; '.join(v) + '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Rolt12 is a musician
Rolt1 is dancer; is an actor
Rolt14 is a singer
```

Comment: how can we print the output into the new text file

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable approach to this problem would be to use a dictionary to store each name's list of occupations. For example, if you have the following set up:

```
data = [("Rolt12", "musician"), ("Rolt1", "dancer"), ("Rolt1", "actor"), ("Rolt14", "singer")]
```

You could use the following code to make a list of occupations for each name:

```
occupations = {}
for name, occupation in data:
    if name not in occupations:
        occupations[name] = []
    occupations[name].append(occupation)
```

Or, more idiomatically:

```
import collections
occupations = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name, occupation in data:
    occupations[name].append(occupation)
```

Then, you can iterate over the dictionary to print the data you want:

```
for name, all_occupations in occupations.items():
    occupations_string = "; ".join(all_occupations)
    print(f"{name} is a {occupations_string}")
```